# openxlsx Error: length of rows and cols must be equal

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I just ran into the same problem that [this](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/openxlsx-Error-length-of-rows-and-cols-must-be-td4726572.html) Nabble user ran into when trying to apply a style to an Excel workbook using a non-rectangular set of rows and columns.

```
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Iris")
writeData(wb, sheet = 1, x = iris)
boldStyle <- createStyle(textDecoration=c("bold"))
addStyle(wb, 1, style = boldStyle, cols=4:5, rows = 1:150)
```

> **Error in addStyle(wb, 1, style = boldStyle, cols = 4:5, rows = 1:150, : Length of rows and cols must be equal.**

How can I fix this code so that I don't get an error and so that I can apply the style to a non-rectangular set of cells?

Answer (score 35):

One of the arguments for addStyle, `gridExpand,` is set to `FALSE` by default.  The trick to get this do what you're attempting is to set this argument to `TRUE.`  This allows the function to apply the style to the combination of rows and columns that were supplied.

Replace the last line with this one and it should work fine:

```
addStyle(wb, 1, style = boldStyle, cols=4:5, rows = 1:150, gridExpand = T)
```

Comment: You asked and answered your question almost at the same time. How did you do it?

Comment: @ycw If you have answers for your questions ready, then both can be posted at the same time.